# Fresher on Network Security

Tags: network, cryptography

Completed my degree course on CS. Cryptography and Network Security was a paper from the course. They were basics, I read the book "Cryptography & Network Security" by Forouzan/Kahate/Stallings. These books are just theoretical. Will anyone tell me that from where I should begin? I have searched the community, posts are showing advanced Network security books. Tell me the name of some books, through which I can learn the practical methods.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by 'practical methods', but i liked this book very much: ['Applied Information Security - Basin, Schaller, Schläpfer'](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642244735)

Comment: Books which are not updated regularly will become useless in the future so I am voting to move this question to meta so that we can help him but not worry about questions going out of use later on.

Comment: You do not say what you want to begin to *do*. "Security" is a very wide field, like "medicine".

Comment: @Limit we get lots of questions asking for books/links. But unless we get a specific goal or purpose, I'm not sure that there is anywhere that can help.

Comment: @schroeder, Yes, I got your point. Well, I am trying to gain knowledge about this field, so that I can further go for PhD, in future.